# Is there such a thing as negative-endorphins?

Tags: endorphins

When I'm feeling quite happy and stub my toe, the feeling of happiness quickly goes away as if my brain has been flooded with a negative version of endorphins. This can last quite a while and it is hard to get back into a happy mood even when the pain subsides.

So is there a negative version of endorphins? Or exactly how do the endorphins dispaear when you stub your toe?

Comment: You may want to search for some article about endorphins, using the terms, like endorphin antagonists. Then you can ask what remains unclear.